# Can an Maximum Likelihood Estimator be 0 or undefined?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I was working on this MLE problem which I derived to be 
\begin{equation*}
    f(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{x\cdot \ln \theta}  
\end{equation*}
where 1 < x < $\theta$
\begin{equation*}
    f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n;\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n\Big(\frac{1}{x_i\cdot \ln \theta}  \Big)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n;\theta) = \Big(\frac{1^n}{\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i)\cdot \ln \theta^n}  \Big)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    L(\theta) = \ln(f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n;\theta)) = \ln\Big(\frac{1^n}{\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i)\cdot \ln \theta^n}  \Big)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    L(\theta) = \ln(1)-  \ln\Big(\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i)\cdot \ln \theta^n\Big) = - \ln\Big(\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i)\Big) + \ln(n\ln \theta)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    L(\theta) = -\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i)\Big) + \ln(n\ln \theta)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{d}{d\theta}(L(\theta)) = -0 + \frac{n}{\theta\ln \left(\theta\right)} = \frac{n}{\theta\ln \left(\theta\right)}
\end{equation*}

Obviously if I set the last equation equal to 0, I will get n to equal zero with $\theta$ being undefined. Is this even possible or did I make a mistake in my math?

Comment: $\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\ln \theta} = \frac{1}{(\ln\theta)^n} \Rightarrow  -n\ln(\ln\theta)$

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't change anything. When I take the derivative the constant comes out, so wether I think the derivative of $n\ln(\ln \theta)$ or  $\ln n(\ln \theta)$ it's still the same. Also it doesn't affect the last step, since it still results in $n = 0$

Comment: Differentiation is not the way to go here - something you can find out if you take a look at the answers to countless similar problems on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made some small mistakes:
\begin{align}
L(\theta) = \ln\Big(\frac{1^n}{\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i)\cdot \ln \theta^n} \Big) &= -\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(x_i) -n\ln(\ln(\theta))
\end{align}
So the derivative for $\theta$ is:
\begin{align}
L'(\theta) = -n\frac{1}{\ln(\theta)}\cdot\frac{1}{\theta}
\end{align}
As you noted setting $L'$ to $0$ doesn't get you far. $L(\theta)$ is decreasing with $\theta$. You also noted that $1<x_i<\theta$ for all $i$. So $\hat{\theta}=\max_i x_i$ is the MLE.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. So when writing out this process, is there a way to prove that setting $\hat{\theta} = max_i(x_i) $ is the correct MLE?

Comment: You could include an indicator in the density: $f(x,\theta) = \mathbb{1}_{x\in[1,\theta]}\frac{1}{x\ln(\theta)}$.

Comment: Thank you, what I am not fully understanding is how setting $\hat{\theta} = max_i(x_i)$ enables me to find the MLE?

Comment: Using this density in the likelihood, gives likelihood zero if any of the $x_i$ is larger than $\theta$. Besides this, it is a matter of calculus. Between $1$ and $\max_i x_i$ the likelihood for $\theta$ is zero with this likelihood. Between $\max_i x_i$ and $\infty$ there are no critical points and $L$ is decreasing, so $\max_i x_i$ is the global maximum and therefore the MLE. I hope I am clear :p

Comment: Yep that cleared it up thanks you!

Comment: Quick question, since 1< x< $\theta$, how come we check between $max x_i$ and $\infty$, wouldn't we only check between $max x_i$ and $\theta$?

Comment: We don't know the actual value of the parameter $\theta$. We are looking for an estimator of $\theta$ that maximizes the likelihood, not for $x_i$.